# Prime factorisation of all Natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just chilled on a Sunday doing Number Theory, need a bit of help please

Q. Show that all powers in prime factorisation of an integer $a>1$ are even $iff$ $a$ is a $perfect-square$.

perfect squares are of the form $n^2$

my attempt, $a=n^2$ with $n=\ p_1^{a_1}.p_k^{a_k} $

$i.e.$ being a prime decomposition of an integer $n$

so $(p_1^{a_1}.p_k^{a_k} )^{2}$ = $n^2$

I hope this makes sense, any light to get me out of the darkness will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k})^2$?

Answer (score 1):

For one direction of the proof, you can just expand your prime factorisation: $$n^2=\left( p_1 ^{a_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{a_k} \right)^2=p_1 ^{2a_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{2a_k}. $$
Hence, every exponent in the prime factorisation of $n^2$ is even.
Now, for the other direction, notice that $$p_1 ^{2a_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{2a_k}=\left( p_1 ^{a_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{a_k} \right)^2 =: n^2$$
Having proven both directions, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this from the opposite direction.

Let $n$ be a natural number. I will use $n=10$ for example. Then, find the prime factors of $n$. $10=2^1\cdot 5^1$. If you square $n$, the powers of it's prime factors will all double. $10^2=2^2\cdot 5^2$.

This true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.